# Regex pattern with positive lookahead and lookbehind

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I have a file looking like:

```
maar beroepsmensen
    p( maar | <s> )     =  0.005859305 [ -2.232154 ]
    p( beroepsmensen | maar ...)    =  7.865118e-06 [ -5.104295 ] # <- first match: 7.865118e-06
    p( kunnen | beroepsmensen ...)  =  6.842439e-08 [ -5.104295 ]
    p( </s> | kunnen ...)   =  0.04018713 [ -1.395913 ]
1 sentences, 2 words, 0 OOVs
0 zeroprobs, logprob= -8.732362 ppl= 814.3052 ppl1= 23237.04

dan scootermobiel
    p( dan | <s> )  =  0.005859305 [ -2.232154 ]
    p( scootermobiel | dan)     =  0.827746 [ -9.106363 ] # <- second match: 0.827746
    p( he | scootermobiel)  =  0.2520393 [ -3.123365 ]
    p( </s> | he ...)   =  0.04499642 [ -1.346822 ]
1 sentences, 2 words, 0 OOVs
```

and a list with some word, e.g. `mylst = ['beroepsmensen', 'scootermobiel']`.

I want to loop through the list and find the first number in the line with the pattern `p( ithwordfromlist | anotherword )    = 9.999999999`. (Please see above for the matches concerning the toyexample). Note that the other word after the `|` can be succeeded by three dots, and that the number sometimes consists of a `e-` structure.

So far, I managed do write a regex, that finds all numbers in front of the `[` with an optional `.` and optional `e-` using a positive lookahead:

`\d+(\.\d+)?(e-\d+)?(?=( )+\[) #the number of spaces after the number can vary too.`

However, I failed to write a positive lookbehind that matches the pattern before the number. For instance, a lookbehind like `(?<=\=( )+)` elicits the error *A quantifier inside a lookbehind makes it non-fixed width*. (Maybe using a lookbehind is not the best approach, so please don't hesitate to propose other solutions too.)

Up to now, I split the long file into a list of lines and apply the regex on every element in that list. However, I could of course also apply it on the whole list, if it would be faster. So if you have solutions for both approaches, please let me know, I will compare the runtime then. Thx!!!

Edit: Insert new lines, which start with structure `p( word1 | word2 )` and should not be matched

Edit2: Make the question more concrete

Answer (score 1):

How about a regex like this:

```
\s*p\s*\(\s*\w+\s*\|\s*\w+\s*\)\s*=\s*([\de\-\.]+)\s*\[\s*[\-\.\de]+\s*\]\s*
```

As seen [here](https://regex101.com/r/6P1fTr/1)

All you need to do is extract group 1 from each match.

The complete code would look like this:

```
import re

pattern = r'\s*p\s*\(\s*\w+\s*\|\s*\w+\s*\)\s*=\s*([\de\-\.]+)\s*\[\s*[\-\.\de]+\s*\]\s*'

f = """maar beroepsmensen
    p( maar | <s> )     =  0.005859305 [ -2.232154 ]
    p( beroepsmensen | maar )    =  7.865118e-06 [ -5.104295 ] # <- first match: 7.865118e-06
    p( </s> | beroepsmensen ...)    =  0.04018713 [ -1.395913 ]
1 sentences, 2 words, 0 OOVs
0 zeroprobs, logprob= -8.732362 ppl= 814.3052 ppl1= 23237.04

dan scootermobiel
    p( dan | <s> )  =  0.005859305 [ -2.232154 ]
    p( scootermobiel | dan)     =  0.827746 [ -9.106363 ] # <- second match: 0.827746
    p( </s> | scootermobiel ...)    =  0.04499642 [ -1.346822 ]
1 sentences, 2 words, 0 OOVs"""

print(re.findall(pattern, f))
```

The output will be `['7.865118e-06', '0.827746']`

Comment: Thx for this solution, Robo Mop. Unfortunately, it got not clear from my toy example, that there can be more lines in the inputfile with the pattern ```\s*p\s*\(\s*\w+\s*\|\s*\w+\s*\)\s*=```. I'll edit my question

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by more lines in the input file?

Comment: Thank you for the comment, because it made clear to me that my question wasn't precise enough. So I'm only interested in the line, where the elements of the list are in the first part of the brackets, such as ```p( ith_word | otherword )```